# Visual Studio 2015 'New Window'/Multiple Instances for HTML files

Tags: html, visual-studio-2015, multiple-instances, new-window

Visual Studio 2015 has the "New Window" button and "Window|New Window" menu item disabled for HTML files.  I need this feature enabled.

I've found ways to do it for VS 2010, but not for VS 2015.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have this problem in 2017, but this post suggests a fix for 2015: http://anirugu.blogspot.hu/2016/06/how-to-open-same-cshtml-file-side-by.html

Answer (score 1):

It work fine in VS2017 community edition.

You can try to create custom toolbar and add it as button from
Window/New Window